# Laravel design. How to show retrieved tags

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, tags

I have an event information page, and I retrieved tags data from my table.
But

> I cannot show tags one by one.

Do I need any Javascript ?
If I need,

> I strongly prefer using vanilla Javascript

, not jquery such as select2 plugin.

I tried many kinds of way by CSS but all the tags are appeared in w3-tag class.

show.blade.php

```
<div class="tag-group">
      Tags: <span class="w3-tag">
           @foreach($post->tags as $tag) {{ $tag->name }} @endforeach
             </span>
 </div>
```

main-info.css

```
.tag-group {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.w3-tag {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  padding: 3px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #626263;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Just that the results of your loop are being displayed in a single HTML tag? You should just write your `span` tag inside the loop then. `@foreach($post->tags as $tag) <span class="w3-tag">{{ $tag->name }}</span> @endforeach`

Comment: You are printing all tags under w3-tag, so it is printing under same class, what do you want to achieve  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="tag-group">
  Tags:
@foreach($post->tags as $tag)
 <span class="w3-tag">
       {{ $tag->name }
 </span>
 @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to achieve.